# How could I optimize my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO inventorydetails 
            (inventoryid, 
             attributekeyid, 
             lssmin) 
SELECT '194572', 
       1, 
       LSS.attributekey 
FROM   transactionlogs TL 
       INNER JOIN lssinventory LSS 
               ON LSS.sapsonumber = TL.sap 
WHERE  TL.sap = '5001044323'
```

Comment: What is problem. I see it's simple only. Can't see any performance issues

Comment: visit this link, which will be so helpful  : http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/#analyze_individual_query

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If the whole query is too slow, then you should first find out if it's the insert part or the select part. Run the `select` on it's own and check how fast that is. Query optimization can quickly become highly vendor specific, so we have to know which DBMS product you are using.

Comment: Actually the select part is very slow. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on the transactionlogs.sap field, and the column you're joining on.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_transactionlogs_sap
ON transactionlogs (sap);
```

Depending on a size of the `transactionlogs` tables, if could hugely improve the performance of the join.

Comment: Hi Sir David Could you please guide me. Im not sure what to do next.

Comment: I've given you the SQL you need?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
INSERT INTO inventorydetails (inventoryid, attributekeyid, lssmin) 
    SELECT '194572', 1, LSS.attributekey 
    FROM transactionlogs TL INNER JOIN
         lssinventory LSS 
         ON LSS.sapsonumber = TL.sap 
    WHERE TL.sap = '5001044323' ;
```

First, if `sap` is a number, drop the single quotes.

Second, you want two indexes for this query:  `transaction_logs(sap)` and `lssinventory(sapsonumber, attributekey)`.